# Using keydown to add a class to the date that's focused on in JqueryUI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I've been trying to get this for about a day now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to add an ADA feature on a datepicker. The datepicker functions like this. You select a start and end date for a search field. I want it so after they select an initial start date that any date focused on after would have a class added to it up until they select an end date. There's some other stuff I need but I can handle that if I can get this resolved.

Here's the part of the code I need help with..

```
$('#calendar').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 39) { //for right arrow key
        $(".between-date").removeClass("between-date"); // reset
        calendar = $(this).closest('.ui-datepicker');
        if (calendar.find('.start-date').length > 0 && calendar.find('.end-date').length == 0) {
            calendar.find('.ui-state-default').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("between-date");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Be careful. You're accidentally declaring `calendar` as a global. Don't forget to add `var` before it to prevent this.

Comment: I actually already declared it in the encapsulating function. I didn't want to post the whole script. Thanks for replying though! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify you question. Why are you trying to use keydown when it JQueryUI's Datepicker only supports clicks? What do you mean by "focused"? Do you mean hover? Are you trying to add a class to the form control or to the calendar?

Comment: @bassxzero, the datepicker is functional using the keyboard once it has focus. ed: however, you traverse the calendar with tab, not the arrow keys.

Comment: @thatpaintingelephant the demo isn't working in IE, FireFox, or Chrome for me. Also, do you really expect end users to learn new controls for a datepicker? Or would you try to add them to every page you used the widget on? https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: @bassxzero, as stated in the OP, this is an ADA feature. the target users are probably used to these controls.